# How to get a scrollable left-hand-side menu in this Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I am trying to modify the CSS code for the underlying Worpress theme for this site: https://isspm2021.webs.upv.es/. The theme is this one: https://wordpress.org/themes/escapade/.

What I am trying to do is get a vertically scrollable left menu when the screen size is, say, 1024 × 768.

This is what I get now:

[image]

As you can see, the last items of the left menu remain hidden and inaccessible, depending on the screen size. I would like the left-hand-side menu to be vertically scrollable when needed.

I've tried several CSS instructions, like `overflow:scroll`, without success.

I think it is because of the theme itself; more precisely, because of the way the different `div` elements are defined to be placed regarding others (`position:relative` and so on).

Any hint of how to modify the CSS style of this theme to get what I need?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest these for the menu to be scrollable:

1. Set a height for the menu part,
2. Set Overflow-y:auto;

Here's the solution:

```
.main-navigation-container, .main-navigation.open, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation .sub-menu {
background-color: #f5f5f5;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 400px;
}
```

Also, If you want the scroll to appear when the browser size is less than 1024px, put the code below:

```
@media all and (max-width:1024px){
 .main-navigation-container, .main-navigation.open, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation .sub-menu {
background-color: #f5f5f5;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 400px;
}
}
```

The above are two options.Please don't insert both of them.Only use one at a time to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept the full left navbar scrollable, you may add `overflow: auto` property in `.side-masthead`:

```
.side-masthead {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    overflow: auto; /* Add overflow property */
}
```